Using Azure AD Graph REST API to reset users password (on behalf)
I'm trying to reset user password using graph rest API with a client ID.I have created application with UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All and added the application to the user administrator as well. When call the request using Postman I am getting following error.  What casuing this problem. I am passing OAuth token for client as well in the headers.

I'm using this end point.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('testing@.example.org')/authentication/methods/{clientid}/resetPassword

I have given following permissions to the application.


What type of permissions you granted in app registration and what authentication flow you used to generate bearer token?

Are you using client credentials flow to generate bearer token via Postman?

Yeah I am using that

Client credentials flow uses permissions of Application type. But Application type permissions are not supported to call this API as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions:~:text=Not%20supported.-,Application,Not%20supported.,-For%20delegated%20scenarios

Alternatively, make use of Update user API to reset user's password that works with token generated using client credentials flow which requires User.ReadWrite.All permission of Application type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-update-the-passwordprofile-of-a-user-and-reset-their-password

Initially, I registered one Entra ID application and granted API permissions as below:

Added the above application to User Administrator directory role like this:

Now, I generated OAuth token using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Response:

When I used this token to reset user's password by calling below API, I too got same error:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/authentication/methods/methodId/resetPassword
{
    "newPassword": "xxxxxxx"
}

Response:


The error occurred as resetting user's password operation  does not  support  Application  permissions as mentioned in this  MS Doc.

Alternatively, you can make use of Update user API call to reset user's password by updating  passwordProfile  property like this:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
    "password": "xxxxxxxx"
  }
}

Response:

Reference:
Update user - Microsoft Graph v1.0 

This is not the user you got token right? You can change any users's password with this request? Cuz i got this error    "message": "Property userPrincipalName is invalid.",
